# Python service gets repoprted as succeeded even though it has failed

Tags: python, linux, service, raspberry-pi

I am running service on the raspberry pi that is meant to run a python script on the startup. Sometimes the python script fails, however when it fails the service still reports it as success which is wrong.

The python script below:

```
import cec
import sys
import time
import configparser
from tuya.devices import TuyaSmartSwitch


class SmartSwitch:
    def __init__(self, config_path):
        CONFIG = configparser.ConfigParser()
        CONFIG.read(config_path)

        try:  # connect to the smart switch
            self.device = TuyaSmartSwitch(
                username=CONFIG["TUYA"]["username"],
                password=CONFIG["TUYA"]["password"],
                location=CONFIG["TUYA"]["location"],
                device=CONFIG["TUYA"]["device"])
        except:
            print("Could not connect to the switch")
            sys.exit()

    def turn_off(self):
        self.device.turn_off()

    def turn_on(self):
        self.device.turn_on()
```

This is the terminal output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/subwoofer_switch $ sudo systemctl status subwoofer.service
● subwoofer.service - My script to control suboowfer smart switch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/subwoofer.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-07-02 19:46:43 BST; 23h ago
  Process: 541 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/subwoofer_switch/subwoofer_control.py (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 541 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 02 19:46:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started My script to control suboowfer smart switch.
Jul 02 19:46:43 raspberrypi python3[541]: Could not connect to the switch
Jul 02 19:46:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: subwoofer.service: Succeeded.
```

As you can see the script did fail the connection and `sys.exit()` should have run and closed the script but it still reports as success.

Here is the service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script to control suboowfer smart switch
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/subwoofer_switch/subwoofer_control.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as my hope was if the service has failed to start it would try again to run the python script

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your code, no parameter is supplied to `sys.exit()`, it defaults to zero, which means *"success"*. So, if your intention is to exit with failure, use:

```
sys.exit(1)
```